# 415 Error in uploading file with android

Tags: android, web-services

I want to upload a mp3 file to a web server and get its response that should be a string but I get 415 error ,HTTP Response is : Cannot process the message because the content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=*****' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.: 415,  here is my code, why does the server refuse this format?

```
public static int upLoad2Server(String sourceFileUri) {
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://address:port/example/mex";
    // String [] string = sourceFileUri;
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.i("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                                            // connection to
                                                            // the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of
                                                        // maximum size
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("Upload file to server", "HTTP Response is : "
                + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        // close streams
        Log.i("Upload file to server", fileName + " File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // this block will give the response of upload link
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("Huzza", "RES Message: " + line);
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.i("Huzza", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
    return serverResponseCode; // like 200 (Ok)

} // end upLoad2Server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code includes this:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
```

and the error is staying that it's expecting `Content-Type` to be this:

```
application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
```

I recommend re-examining why you're setting the content type to something other than the server accepts.

Comment: Though I change content type of next one but still getting same 415 EC